# Get stack status through REST API without mentioning Tenant/Project id in devstack

Tags: rest, openstack, devstack, openstack-heat

All,

I want to get status of newly orchestrated stack in devstack though REST API. I am using following method to get the status and it is successful.

```
GET http://10.0.124.61:8004/v1/<tenant_id>/stacks/<stack_id>
```

But, the challenge is sometime, I may not be able to get tenant ID.So, is there a possibility to get stack status without tenant id?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tenant ID is mandatory to get stack status and that's how the openstack resources can be invoked with Tenant id.  You can make use of openstack python sdk for an easy way of access to openstack resources.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the port in API Access page but the result is coming from `..:35357/v2.0/` :

```
curl --request GET \
     --url http://controller:35357/v2.0/tenants \
     --header 'X-Auth-Token: gAAAAABkRNpw0ewH9FnL72w6L....'
```

[image]